# I get "error while initializing app engine" while trying to create appengine Application on GCP

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am using the console. I'm getting this error on the first stage (Configure application). I have tried to create an appengine application on multiple GCP accounts but I'm getting the same error "error while initializing app engine".

[image: 1]

I have tried using different GCP accounts.
I have tried adding my card details.

Comment: I encountered the same issue, but it was due to already having a datastore/firestore database for that project. I needed to create the app engine app in the same region as my datastore to get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I observed the same problem on April 14, having tried many times with different locations.

What worked was using the `gcloud` CLI tool on a local machine (you could also try online with "Activate Cloud Shell"):

```
gcloud auth login
gcloud config set project <project>
gcloud app create
```